# HTTP-Pipeline gone mad with mobile Safari?

Tags: apache, tomcat, safari, webserver

We have a (dynamic) WebApplication and are trying to solve some perfomance issues: When look at our our Apache-Logs it seems that a specific user agent (Safari) is sending multiple IDENTICAL requests during 1 second.

It may have to do with the implemtation of Pipelining in the mobile Version of Safari.

The log entries look like the following lines:

> 188.102.30.71 - - [16/Jan/2017:21:20:41 +0100] "GET /an/existing/path?a=b >HTTP/1.1" 200 407380 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_2 like Mac OS >X) AppleWebKit/602.3.12 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14C92 >Safari/602.1" /0 /487136
>   188.102.30.71 - - [16/Jan/2017:21:20:42 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 12876 "-" >"MobileSafari/602.1 CFNetwork/808.2.16 Darwin/16.3.0" /0 /79180
>   188.102.30.71 - - [16/Jan/2017:21:20:42 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 12876 "-" >"MobileSafari/602.1 CFNetwork/808.2.16 Darwin/16.3.0" /0 /31172
>   188.102.30.71 - - [16/Jan/2017:21:20:42 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 12876 "-" >"MobileSafari/602.1 CFNetwork/808.2.16 Darwin/16.3.0" /0 /25425
>   "and more of them..."

It seems that for 1 real user action we receive the identical request for another resource (here the /) several times (8 - 10 times).

Is this the Apple-Implementation of Pipelining? We don't see other User Agents with this behaviour.

Is there a way to prevent these requests? We use Apache for delivering our content.

I am glad for any hints and suggestions which may help to solve this problem.

Tino